# Need to redirect Parent Taxonomy Term page to oldest child

Tags: views

I use the Views version of the taxonomy listing page.  For performance reasons, I can't use a depth of 1 on the 'Taxonomy Term (depth)' contextual filter.

Unfortunately, for one taxonomy, ALL terms are a child of this one set of six terms (think Publication / Issues of a magazine).  Is there a way I can, in my menu, link to the parent terms, yet have that listing page show only the nodes from the most recent child?

Otherwise, is there a way, in that View, to have an increased depth (1 vs 0) ONLY if there are no nodes for the particular term?

Answer (score 0):

So I figured this out, wasn't too complicated at all.  Use hook_menu. I didn't write my SQL using the Drupal DB API, but it works:

```
function ain_custom_menu() {


 $items = array();

  // Item1
  $items['taxonomy/term/218489'] = array(
    'title' => 'Title1',
    'page callback' => 'MYMODULE_find_newsletter',
    'page arguments' => array("218489"),
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
  );

  // Item2
  $items['taxonomy/term/218500'] = array(
    'title' => 'Title2',
    'page callback' => 'MYMODULE_find_newsletter',
    'page arguments' => array("218500"),
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
  );

  return $items;

}

function MYMODULE_find_newsletter($mytid) {
  $tid = db_query('SELECT max(tid) AS tid FROM taxonomy_term_hierarchy t1 
    JOIN field_data_field_pubissue t2 ON t1.tid = t2.field_pubissue_tid
    JOIN node t3 ON t2.entity_id = t3.nid
    WHERE t1.parent = '.$mytid.' AND t3.status = 1')->fetchField();
  $latest = is_numeric($tid) ? 'taxonomy/term/' . $tid : '<front>';
  drupal_goto($latest);
}
```